# Program receiving SIGSEGV may be for pointer of 0xffffffff

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am debugging a program in user space and is receiving a `SIGSEGV` for a pointer which I think may be for value `0xffffffff`.

I want to know if `0xffffffff` is a valid pointer address ??

I used GDB and below is list of code:

```
1414
1415        /* convert object handle */
1416        file = (PSLhandle_t*)hFile;
1417
1418        /* param check */
1419        if(file->hobject.fdesc == 0)   <----------------- it may be crashing here
1420            return INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER;





----------------- during debugging---------------------------


1412        if((hFile == NULL) || (lpBuffer == NULL))
(gdb) s
1419        if(file->hobject.fdesc == 0)
(gdb) print file
No symbol "file" in current context.
(gdb) print hFile
$1 = (HANDLE) 0xffffffff
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
WriteFile (hFile=0xffffffff, lpBuffer=0xb7f69294, nNumberOfBytesToWrite=65516, lpNumberOfBytesWritten=0xb3933238,
    lpOverlapped=0x0) at PSLWinWrapper.c:1419
1419        if(file->hobject.fdesc == 0)
```

I am using Linux ,

[root@DellB app]# uname -a
Linux DellB 2.6.23.1-42.fc8 #1 SMP 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

I have already checked for `NULL`.

```
/* param check */
if((hFile == NULL) || (lpBuffer == NULL)) <-------- CHECKED ALREADY FOR NULL
    return INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER;

/* convert object handle */
file = (PSLhandle_t*)hFile;

/* param check */
if(file->hobject.fdesc == 0) <-------------- CRASH HERE
    return INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER;
```

I want to know if `0xffffffff` is a valid pointer address?
Is there any API which can validate is the pointer is valid on LINUX in userspace.

Comment: Just a guess but you're not trying to cast a unix file handle to a FILE stream pointer are you?  They're fundamentally different things, you need to use `fdopen()`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe `0xffffffff` is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, at least on 32-bit systems.

Many Windows API functions return `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` in order to indicate that an error occurred.  For example, from the `CreateFile` documentation ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)):

> #### Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the specified file, device, named pipe, or mail slot.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

In general, any pointer value *could* point to valid memory, including `NULL`.  But many operating systems and language runtimes reserve a space near 0 for invalid pages, in order to provide programmers with useful crashes when they dereference `NULL`.  This space can extend in both directions, in which case it includes `0xffffffff` on 32-bit systems.  And no object in a C/C++ system will ever have an address at `NULL` (so if there is something at `NULL`, it's probably best left alone).

**Your second question:** Yes, there is a way to check to see if a pointer points to valid memory on Linux (this is a slightly different concept than "valid pointer").  Dereference the pointer and see if your program segfaults.  Install a signal handler to catch the fault, use a long jump to return from the signal handler.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is not the only invalid pointer value.
In general, accessing any pointer which was not obtained in one of the normal ways (such as the address of a variable or the return value of `malloc`) is undefined behavior. This doesn't mean accessing it will crash, but it does mean it might crash.

So testing for `NULL` doesn't guarantee that a pointer is valid.

Specifically, `0xffffffff` is invalid in almost any common platform.
Even if it's valid, and points to the last byte in memory, you can only access this one byte, because the following byte is at address `0`, which is surely invalid.

Comment: Most architectures permit you to put data at address `0` , as well as `0xffffffff`.  (However, accessing a word starting at `0xffffffff` will almost certainly fault, even on x86.  That's not to say it will fail, per se.)  Most operating systems will also allow you to place data at address 0.  So a `NULL` pointer on most systems isn't guaranteed to be invalid, it's just guaranteed to be unequal to any pointer returned from a standard C function or any pointer correctly derived from such a pointer.  This is really about the OS and programming conventions, not the architecture.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, I think for major operating systems on major platforms, accessing `NULL` crashes. I'm sure about Windows+Linux on x86(_64). But you're right that a `NULL` pointer isn't guaranteed to be invalid, and accessing it isn't guaranteed to crash (I don't think anything in the C standard is guaranteed to crash).

Comment: Yes, it's invalid on most major platforms.  My point is that it's valid from an architectural standpoint, e.g., x86/ARM/PowerPC/etc, instead it's the OS/runtime that makes the decision about which pointers are valid.  So saying "`0xffffffff` is invalid in almost any architecture" is not correct, and it's different from saying "`0xffffffff` is invalid in major desktop/server platforms", which is true.

Comment: Edited a bit to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, 0xffffffff is the unsigned value of the 32 bit signed integer -1.  A likely cause of your problem is that whatever function returns the value for hFile is erring out and returning -1.  Most sane programs return NULL, which has the integer value 0, on error when the return type is a pointer. This case may be an exception.  Can you show where hFile was originally assigned?

Comment: `(void *)-1` is not that rare for system calls, especially ones that can return `NULL` on success.  `mmap` is probably the most common example, but all of the `HANDLE`-returning functions in the Windows API use the same convention.